# What is the use of the diode connected anti parallel to the gate resistance in the general MOSFET/IGBT gate driver circuit?

Tags: mosfet, diodes, power-electronics, gate-driving, igbt

From my limited knowledge, the only advantage of providing a parallel path through diode with a lower resistance across the main gate resistance is the high speed turn off of the power electronic device. Is there anything else behind this kind of design?[image: High side driver section]

Answer (score 1):

To have different rise and fall times. These are usually different in a MOSFET anyways and you have shoot-through to worry about if two MOSFETs are stacked like in a half-bridge.

Comment: So are we trying to make them equal?

Comment: @VivekVijayan Or make it turn off faster than it turns on for shoot-through reasons, as you can see in your schematic: 10R for discharge but 100R for charge

Comment: Sometimes it's good to turn one FET off before turning the other one on... This is one way to accomplish that, but not the best. I would check the driver IC to look at its dead time options.